# ContextMenu for table xml excel

Tags: xml, excel, vba, ribbonx

Today, I was looking for a method for customize contextual menu in excel. I found this topic useful:

http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s6/win001.htm

However in the following XML code, this snnipet idMso="ContextMenuCell" doesn't work under any circumstances. I spent several hours looking for a table object id for idMso.

```
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui">
   <contextMenus>
      <contextMenu idMso="ContextMenuCell">
         <dynamicMenu id="MyDynamicMenu" 
        label= "My Dynamic Menu" imageMso="HappyFace" 
        getContent="GetContent" insertBeforeMso="Cut"/>
      </contextMenu>
   </contextMenus>
</customUI>
```

Comment: You should answer your own question in the answers.

Comment: Providing an answer to your own question is completely okay and also often quite useful. However, you should not answer in the question; post your answer as a separate answer instead. The question should really only contain the question.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your advise.

Answer (score 7):

Try using idMso="ContextMenuListRange" for excel table context menu modification.

Comment: That worked. Is there documentation anywhere, or are you just supposed to guess?